# Adding songs to a playlist in Android Q (API29) and above throws a SecurityException

Tags: java, android

Because of the **Android Privacy Changes in Android Q (API29)** it's not possible to add songs to a Playlist and it throws this error message when adding a track.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: com.mp3player.mp3player has no access to content://media/external_primary/audio/media/117
```

I know that we can this catch this as a `RecoverableSecurityException` and grant permission for each file individually.

But this is really a hassle and i'm wondering if there is another way.

I already found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398381/api-29-mediastore-access) from User @Theo with the same exact problem but without any answers.

**Code for adding songs to a playlist**

```
public void addToPlayList(Context c, long songID, long playListID, String playlistName) {

    Uri playListUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playListID);

    String[] columns = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER,
    };

    ContentResolver resolver = c.getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(playListUri, columns, null, null, null);

    int playOrder = 0;
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            playOrder = cursor.getInt(0) + 1;
        }
        cursor.close();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID, songID);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER, playOrder);

        resolver.insert(playListUri, contentValues);
        resolver.notifyChange(Uri.parse("content://media"), null);
}
```

**EDIT**

Looks like the thrown **Exception** is not an instance of `RecoverableSecurityException` so how do we get access to that content?

Comment: can you find solution?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147619577

Answer (score -1):

you can use  `playListUri.getpath()` and solve it.

Comment: Please expand your answer with an example and explain how the solution works. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer