# How to add music to the playlist in Android 10

Tags: android, playlist, android-music-player

this is my code.

```
    public boolean addToPlaylist(long audioId, long playlistId, String musicTitle) {

 
    Uri playListUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playlistId);

    String[] columns = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER,
    };


    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(playListUri, columns, null, null, null);

    int playOrder = 0;
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            playOrder = cursor.getInt(0) + 1;
        }
        cursor.close();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID, audioId);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER, playOrder);

        resolver.insert(playListUri, contentValues);
        resolver.notifyChange(Uri.parse("content://media"), null);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

my app crashed with this code on api 29.
error :
com.aliriahi.baritm has no access to content://media/external_primary/audio/media/28

Answer (score -1):

Add these permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: No solution but more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398381/api-29-mediastore-access