# RecoverableSecurityException no access to content://media/external/audio/media

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-music-player

I have a music player app, and it used to work when I tried to delete a file. However, since API 29, I'm getting the following error when I tried to delete the file via the contentResolver.delete.

android.app.RecoverableSecurityException: musicplayer has no access to content://media/external/audio/media/1324

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + mSongList.get(selectedPosition).getSongName());
alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
                                    contentResolver.delete(mSongList.get(selectedPosition).getSongUri(), null, null);
        mSongList.remove(selectedPosition);
        mAdapterListFile.notifyDataSetChanged();
        serviceMusic.setSongList(mSongList);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    alert.show();
```

Comment: looks related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59736650/5482166

Comment: yah, but I can do it with other people's app. Using their app, I was able to delete the file. Is there any alternative to my delete method in the new API?

Answer (score 1):

You should take `recoverableSecurityException.userAction.actionIntent.intentSender` from exception and using `Activity.startIntentSenderForResult()` aks the permission to delete the file. 
Check this sample project:
https://github.com/android/storage-samples/tree/main/MediaStore

Comment: The linked project is written in Kotlin, the OP has asked in Java. Could you please provide Java code - or a link to Java code?